# Is there any difference between KeyEvent and hardware Key Press in android?

Tags: android, events, hardware, key

If i programatically code KEYEVENT in android for KEYCODE_ENTER, is this exactly same as hardware ENTER key click in android??

Please Help!!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I think its  same but the main benefit is we can control the event that should occur when we programatically code KEYEVENT in android which is not possible with the hardware buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply...For an inbuilt activity like MessagingActivity can i get its click using the KEYEVENT KEYCODE ENTER??

Comment: I never tried this but I think its possible. you can check it ...:)